# Java Minesweeper - non-square board counting mines in the wrong place

Tags: java, arrays

I'm writing a Minesweeper program in Java. It works perfectly if I use a square (nxn) board, but if I use a non-square board, say 10x15, my counter function produces some strange results. See the image below:

[image: Minesweeper board]

It looks like the counts correspond to the squares adjacent to mines that have a count of 0. So the counts seem to be translating, I just can't figure out why this might be happening exactly. But there is clearly a link to non-square boards, since as I said, it works fine for square boards. Here's the relevant code. `buttons` is just the 2D button array. `WIDTH` and `HEIGHT` is the width and height of the board in terms of number of buttons. `isMine` is just a boolean, self-explanatory. Any ideas?

```
for (int x = 0; x < buttons[0].length; x++) {
  for (int y = 0; y < buttons.length; y++) {
     if(!buttons[y][x].isMine) {
        countSurrounding(y, x);
     }
  }
}

// returns 1 if there's a mine at y,x or 0 if there isn't
int mineAt(int y, int x) {
   if(y >= 0 && y < HEIGHT && x >= 0 && x < WIDTH && buttons[y][x].isMine) { //check for bounds
      return 1;
   } 
   else {
      return 0;
   }
}

void countSurrounding(int y, int x) {
    int mines = 0;
    mines += mineAt(y - 1, x - 1);  // NW
    mines += mineAt(y - 1, x);      // N
    mines += mineAt(y - 1, x + 1);  // NE
    mines += mineAt(y, x - 1);      // W
    mines += mineAt(y, x + 1);      // E
    mines += mineAt(y + 1, x - 1);  // SW
    mines += mineAt(y + 1, x);      // S
    mines += mineAt(y + 1, x + 1);  // SE
    buttons[y][x].neighbourCount = mines;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not see any issue with the code you have shared. I recreated it in acii art :) and it works perfectly. So the issue must be in the code you did not suspect :)

```
public class Main {


private int HEIGHT = 15;
private int WIDTH = 10;

private boolean[][] buttons = new boolean [HEIGHT][WIDTH];

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Main m = new Main();
    m.init();
    m.printMines();

}

void init(){
    for (int x = 0; x < buttons[0].length; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < buttons.length; y++) {
           buttons[y][x] = false;
        }
    }
    buttons[11][1] =  true;
    buttons[12][3] =  true;
    buttons[7][3] =  true;
    buttons[12][6] =  true;
    buttons[2][4] =  true;

}

void printMines(){
    for (int x = 0; x < buttons[0].length; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < buttons.length; y++) {
            if(!buttons[y][x]) {
                System.out.print(countSurrounding(y, x));
            }else {
                System.out.print('X');
            }

        }
        System.out.print('\n');
    }

}




// returns 1 if there's a mine at y,x or 0 if there isn't
int mineAt(int y, int x) {
    if(y >= 0 && y < HEIGHT && x >= 0 && x < WIDTH && buttons[y][x]) { //check for bounds
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}

int countSurrounding(int y, int x) {
    int mines = 0;
    mines += mineAt(y - 1, x - 1);  // NW
    mines += mineAt(y - 1, x);      // N
    mines += mineAt(y - 1, x + 1);  // NE
    mines += mineAt(y, x - 1);      // W
    mines += mineAt(y, x + 1);      // E
    mines += mineAt(y + 1, x - 1);  // SW
    mines += mineAt(y + 1, x);      // S
    mines += mineAt(y + 1, x + 1);  // SE
    return mines;
}
```

}